# SELECT STATMENT IN OR LIKE OR REGEXP

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table *new_table*

```
ID            DESCRIPTION
1             abdad jadjnd kandkadn 01/19-P-154-37
2             jscbsjc jscnscj 01/19-H-443-38 sbjcj sjcnjscn
3             scjbcs sc, scnsc 01/19-P-16-39 sjcbnjcs
4             scbcsjc 01/19-K-139-40 hcbchsb
```

AND *LISTS*

```
01/19-P-154-37
01/19-H-443-38
01/19-K-139-40
```

I want to

```
select * from new_table where descriptin in (
01/19-P-154-37
01/19-H-443-38
01/19-P-16-39
01/19-K-139-40
)
```

OR LIKE I don't now please help

Comment: What is `LISTS`? another table ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want something like this (join with like operator):

```
with new_table (ID,            DESCRIPTION) as (
    select 1 ,'abdad jadjnd kandkadn 01/19-P-154-37' from dual union all
    select 2 ,'jscbsjc jscnscj 01/19-H-443-38 sbjcj sjcnjscn' from dual union all
    select 3 ,'scjbcs sc, scnsc 01/19-P-16-39 sjcbnjcs' from dual union all
    select 4 ,'scbcsjc 01/19-K-139-40 hcbchsb' from dual
) ,
LISTS(val) as(
    select '01/19-P-154-37' from dual union all
    select '01/19-H-443-38' from dual union all
    select '01/19-K-139-40' from dual  
)

-- Below is actual query:    

select new_table.* from new_table 
inner join LISTS
on new_table.DESCRIPTION   like '%'||LISTS.val||'%'
```

Comment: I have a 700 row in list

Comment: @Tiko - ... and ?

Comment: `regexp_like(DOC.DESCRIPTION,'01/19-M-33-01|
01/19-M-31-02|
01/19-A-1-03|
01/19-D-2-04|
01/19-X-8-05|
01/19-14/1204-06|
01/19-D-29-07|
01/19-U-116-08|
01/19-U-118-09|
01/19-X-48-10|
01/19-14/1205-11|
01/19-E-5-12|
01/19-14/1206-13|
01/19-M-151-14')`